# How to validate array of arrays in Symfony 4

Tags: symfony, symfony4

I want to know how can I validate array of arrays in symfony. 
My validation rules are:

1. User - NotBlank
2. Date - Date and NotBlank
3. Present - NotBlank

So far I have done this:

```
$validator = Validation::createValidator();

$constraint = new Assert\Collection(array(
        'user' => new Assert\NotBlank(),
        'date' => new Assert\Date(),
        'present' => new Assert\NotBlank()
));

$violations = $validator->validate($request->request->get('absences')[0], $constraint);
```

But the problem is that it only allows to validate single array eg.
`$request->request->get('absences')[0]`.

Here is how the array looks like:

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use a custom constraint/validator in symfony form type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35870980/use-a-custom-constraint-validator-in-symfony-form-type)

Comment: Where do you see the duplicate?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have to put the [Collection](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/Collection.html) constraint inside [All](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/constraints/All.html) constraint:

> When applied to an array (or Traversable object), this constraint allows you to apply a collection of constraints to each element of the array.

So, your code will probably look like this:

```
$constraint = new Assert\All(['constraints' => [
    new Assert\Collection([
        'user' => new Assert\NotBlank(),
        'date' => new Assert\Date(),
        'present' => new Assert\NotBlank()
    ])
]]);
```

Update: if you want to use annotations for this, it'll look something like this:

```
@Assert\All(
    constraints={
        @Assert\Collection(
            fields={
                "user"=@Assert\NotBlank(),
                "date"=@Assert\Date(),
                "present"=@Assert\NotBlank()
            }
        )
    }
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I was looking at the All assertion, but did not figure it out, that I can pass Collection into all Assertion.

Comment: Hi how do you write this in annotation form?

Comment: Hi @reddy, sorry, I only just saw your question. I updated my answer.

Comment: How to validate if there's `items > 0` :) ?